# While querying a json file from groovy getting null response

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jq, jenkins-groovy

I am using below snippet in my jenking groovy file, where I am getting null response.

```
def Services= sh(script: "curl -s --header \"PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${gittoken}\" ${url}| jq -r .${Servicename}[]", returnStdout: true)
```

file which I am downloading is like below.

```
{
  "FrameWork1": [
    "sample/sample1",
    "sample/sample2"
  ]
 
}
```

Basically I am getting values of Framework1

if I give below one I am getting the first value of Framework object

Working one:###############

```
def Services= sh(script: "curl -s --header \"PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${gittoken}\" ${url}| jq -r .${Servicename}[1]", returnStdout: true)
```

Comment: your question is about `jq` tool.

Answer (score 0):

`jq` filter should be `.FrameWork1[]` to get a list of strings

https://jqplay.org/s/3iCv-off4ep

Comment: Sry I assigned a variable servicename like this def Servicename = "FrameWork1" in the previous step

Answer (score 0):

Don't use shell parameter expansion to generate the jq program, pass the shell parameters as arguments to jq instead (then you do not have to worry about contexts, quoting, escaping, etc.)

```
... | jq -r --arg svc "$Servicename" '.[$svc][]'
```